# What exactly is meant by session in the context of a Web Application

Tags: session

I did a little bit of Web Programming here and there but I never quite understood what's meant by the word `Session`.

I've googled a bit here and there, read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29) article, but could never quite grasp the meaning of it.

So, what's a Session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Session is a way of persisting your information across multiple pages and requests. When you visit the login page of any site and you provide your username and password, you won't need to provide them again on subsequent pages.

This is done by attaching a session id, unique to your request, and is sent back and forth as you navigate pages.

Session Id could be stored in cookies (file on your system), in the URL as part of query string or in the database

Answer (score 3):

A session is a place for storing data for a particular visitor of your site.

You can store data there that is also available on the next page request from that visitor. If some data is stored 'in the session', it means that the data is stored somewhere (possibly in the database of the server or in files) which the server can then use to construct the web page.

The visitor will receive a temporary cookie which contains a session id, an identifier which is used to associate that visitor with the session data that is stored on the web server.

The session id is sent to the server with each request and the server can lookup the stored session data (which can then be used to construct the web page).

Answer (score 3):

It's the concept of keeping state around over an inherently stateless protocol like HTTP.

If you want to keep track of a logged-in user, for example, and maybe some data associated with that user, you could send that data between the server and the client each time, which of course would be terribly insecure. Or you could keep it in a session store on the server, for example a file or a database, and just exchange an identifier for the storage location between client and server. That's usually done via cookies these days, but could also be a parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple:

If you first visit the site, the server gives the client an identifier. With this the server can identify a client across several request from the client to the server. The identifier is deleted after a preset time.

The combination of this identifier and the timeframe the identifier is valid, is called session.

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Session:** An interaction between user & server, which has an ID associated with it. So that server can pin-point & serve the users according to their requests. Cookies are basically used for storing the session information because by default HTTP is state-less.